# Adding a device for ios development produces provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Does anybody know why the following error occurs when I try to use an iPhone 5 running iOS 7 for development? I tried refreshing my provisioning profiles and they are valid and up-to-date...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out more information about the provisioning profiles that are currently in Xcode by downloading the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465). It will show you details such as how many devices are in profiles, the date they were generated, the app ID for the profile, etc. It will also let you delete and re-add profiles, so you could delete the profile and then manually add it by downloading it from the iOS Developer portal.

You may also try deleting and re-adding the profile on the device that you're currently testing with.

Comment: there are currently no provisioning profile associated with the device because they won't install in the first place

Comment: Did you add the device to the devices list in the provisioning section on the iOS developer portal?

Comment: Yes and it says that it's a valid device. There's also a different device that I'm using that does work

Comment: Try disconnecting the device from your computer, deleting the device from the devices list in Xcode, and reconnecting the device. See if that makes the issue go away.

Comment: that did nothing unfortunately